# Real word for "patternistic"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The context I was writing in:

> "I hypothesized that due to the **patternistic** structure of Active Directory environments and the frequency of their use [...]"

The word seems like it would fit but it's unfortunately not a real word. What would be the closest alternative?

Comment: "...due to the patterned structure..."

Comment: If *structure* already has a pattern, wouldn't that word suffice?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Perhaps. Perhaps I have too much of a love for adjectives.

Comment: Voting to close because I'd need you to explain what you're trying to convey with "patternistic" before I could propose any alternatives.

Comment: If you want a word that means characterized by or resembling patterns, _OED_ lists _patterny_ and _pattern-like_. They are uncommon but self-explanatory. I believe _pattern-like_ is the most suitable one and the definition in _OED_ is: "Conforming to or resembling a pattern; characterized by regularity."  _Patterned_ is a common adjective but it has the strong sense of having or decorated with patterns.

Comment: *Regular* or *structured* are also commonly used in this context. *Regular* means having elements recurring in a fixed pattern; *structured* means having a (partially) fixed structure or pattern of elements, but not necessarily as regular (e.g. a mix of long and short fields). *Structured data* and similar phrases are common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [***recurring***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/recurring)?

> **recurring**
> /rɪˈkəːrɪŋ/
>
> *adjective*
>
> : occurring again periodically or repeatedly.
>
> *'gratitude is a **recurring** theme in the book'*